# Binding with Winforms Controls and Entity Framework NO DATAGRID

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, textbox, label, dbcontext

Are there any examples that show how to integrate winforms controls with entity framework 6 that DO NOT use DATAGRID?

I need an example of how to use it with textboxes, labels and such. The only ones I can find are DATAGRID examples.

Comment: Here's an example toward bottom. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221931/Entity-Framework-in-WinForms

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks for the help. I had found this earlier, and just didn't dive into the control.  I have since taken a look at how this control works and see now that I much of the magic happens in the custom datasource object called entityDatasource.